# Filter pandas dataframe by list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

I have a dataframe that has a row called "Hybridization REF". I would like to filter so that I only get the data for the items that have the same label as one of the items in my list.

Basically, I'd like to do the following:

```
dataframe[dataframe["Hybridization REF"].apply(lambda: x in list)]
```

but that syntax is not correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update using reindex,

```
df.reindex(collist, axis=1)
```

and

```
df.reindex(rowlist, axis=0)
```

and both:

```
df.reindex(index=rowlist, columns=collist)
```

---

You can use .loc or column filtering:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(5,5),columns=list('ABCDE'),index=list('abcde'))

df
          A         B         C         D         E
a  0.460537  0.174788  0.167554  0.298469  0.630961
b  0.728094  0.275326  0.405864  0.302588  0.624046
c  0.953253  0.682038  0.802147  0.105888  0.089966
d  0.122748  0.954955  0.766184  0.410876  0.527166
e  0.227185  0.449025  0.703912  0.617826  0.037297

collist = ['B','D','E']

rowlist = ['a','c']
```

Get columns in list:

```
df[collist]
```

Output:

```
          B         D         E
a  0.174788  0.298469  0.630961
b  0.275326  0.302588  0.624046
c  0.682038  0.105888  0.089966
d  0.954955  0.410876  0.527166
e  0.449025  0.617826  0.037297
```

Get rows in list

```
df.loc[rowlist]

          A         B         C         D         E
a  0.460537  0.174788  0.167554  0.298469  0.630961
c  0.953253  0.682038  0.802147  0.105888  0.089966
```

Answer (score 21):

Suppose 
`df` is your `dataframe`,
`lst` is our `list` of labels.

```
df.loc[ df.index.isin(lst), : ]
```

Will display all rows whose index matches any value of the list item. I hope this helps solve your query.

Answer (score 11):

Is there a numpy dataframe? I am guessing it is pandas dataframe, if so here is the solution.

```
df[df['Hybridization REF'].isin(list)]
```

Comment: This filter works and I prefer this way. You can read the docs [how to filtering dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/indexing.html#indexing-and-selecting-data) this way.

Answer (score 1):

Same code with this correction should work.

```
dataframe[dataframe["Hybridization REF"].apply(lambda x : x in list)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
df.loc[ df.index.intersection(lst), : ]
```

This way you only get the intersection

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df.query('`Hybridization REF` == @list')
```

The `` ` ``'s before and after `Hybridization REF` are needed due to the whitespace in the column name. With `@` you can access the variable `list`.

Keep in mind that Python's built-in list type is named *list*. So it is a good idea to rename this variable.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, if you are looking to match just a sub portion of your string you can also use:

```
new_df = df.loc[df.index.str.contains('sub_string_you_need'), :]
```